# How to use smote function and XGboost in R at the same time

Tags: r, xgboost, smote

Anyone knows how to use smote function and XGboost in R at the same time? I used smote function to balance the classes first, then use XGboost for training. However, one of the parameters in the xgb.cv function is label, which requires as.matrix type, meaning the data must be numeric. But when i used smote function, i converted the target variable to factor because it is required. Now i can not use xgb.

Comment: I remember using the `mlr` environment teo years ago where I used XGBoost in combination with SMOTE. I can't remember anymore if tehre has been an issue, but I know it worked. The `mlr` environment has updated to `mlr3`, which I haven't used, so not sure how you would set up your pipeline there: https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/